# Bad OpenVPN Uninstall

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, apt-get

On my Ubuntu 18.04 machine I installed OpenVPN and then later tried to uninstall. Now whenever I try to install anything or do pretty much anything with `apt-get` I get an error and the package doesnt install. This is what happens when I try to install something:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  openvpn
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  yarn
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 100 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/833 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,849 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 183666 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing openvpn (2.4.4-2ubuntu1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package openvpn (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/etc/openvpn/server': Not a directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openvpn
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue by making a file called `/etc/openvpn` instead of a folder.

Try removing the invalid file/folder `/etc/openvpn`:

```
sudo rm -rfv /etc/openvpn
```

Then remove the `openvpn` package:

```
sudo apt purge -y openvpn
```